# Cocoa and Insteon devices

Tags: cocoa, home-automation

I'm looking to tinker with some insteon devices (so I can monitor a basement water softner and water heater) and Cocoa, see if I can build an app. So coming into this with no knowledge about home automation here's my first question.

I'm looking at a set up like this:

Insteon AppliancLinc module-->PowerLinc Controller-->Mac Mini (forgot the exact specs but it is a G5 running Leopard) and I'll most times remote into it from a PowerBook, though I am getting my two older kids iPads for Christmas so I might like to build an app to work from there once I get the cocoa one working...

How do I access the data on the PowerLinc controller? Since it is USB will it just appear as a device? Is there a Cocoa/Linux API?

Insteon has a SDK kit for $99, which also gets you two devices but it seems that it is a Window's only environment:

http://www.smarthome.com/insteon/sdk2600s.html
http://www.docklight.de/download_en.htm

Thanks for the help.